# How to set content to a particular label inside a cell in data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a checkbox and label (i'e serial numbers) inside first column in a data table.After delete a row from data table i have to update label content(i'e serial numbers) and checkbox should be fixed for all columns.I tried following code but after delete a row the checkboxes are resets(gets disappears) and it displays only serial numbers.

```
owner_table = $('#owners_table').DataTable();
owner_table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    owner_table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    });
}).draw();
```

The HTML code

```
<label> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="verify_check" id="verify_check<?php echo $i; ?>" name="verify_check" value="<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"> 
    <label id="sno"> <?php echo $i; ?></label> 
</label>
```

Comment: <label>
<input type="checkbox" class="verify_check" id="verify_check<?php echo $i; ?>" name="verify_check" value="<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>"> <label id="sno"> <?php echo $i; ?></label>
 </label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use the following code for [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) function to update particular element inside the cell:

```js
drawCallback: function(settings){            
   var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
   api.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
      var serial = i + 1;
      $(".index", cell).html(serial);
      $("input", cell).attr({
         'value': serial,
         'id': 'verify_check' + serial
      });
   } );            
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk3Losm6/) for code and demonstration.